# Facebook Like Button Refreshes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been using facebook api for a time, but recently there is a problem,
i have put fblike on different pages of my website.
Now some of them are working some of them are not working, but they were working perfect last week.
Is this my problem or problem at facebook end?

Comment: Please add some code, because I can't help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug reported last week (check http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18591) but this has been marked as fixed since yesterday.

What is the error that you are experiencing? Can you provide a link or some sample code for your like button.

Have you tried linting your pages? Do you get any errors there?  (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint)